# nextInt() caused an infinit loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My expectation:

If the user types an Int which is not in the right range, the program will give him another chance until the user gives the right type.

So, I need a `while` block. But I got an infinite loop.

My code:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestInput {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        boolean keepRunning = true;
        while (keepRunning) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Start --- ");
                Integer selection = inputSelection();
                //Integer selection = Integer.parseInt(selectionString);
                String email;
                switch (selection) {
                    case 1:
                        // inputDate();
                        System.out.println("Do 1");

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //inputEmail();
                        System.out.println("Do 2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //inputName();
                        System.out.println("Do 3");

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        // Exit
                        keepRunning = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Please enter a number 1 to 4: ");
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Integer inputSelection () {
        Integer selection = 0;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                selection = scanner.nextInt();  // reads only one int. does not finish the line.
                scanner.nextLine(); // consume '\n' to finish the line
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return selection;
    }
}
```

DOCs I read:

[Resetting a .nextLine() Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991494/resetting-a-nextline-scanner)

[Using Scanner.nextLine() after Scanner.nextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465066/using-scanner-nextline-after-scanner-nextint)

[Scanner error with nextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832006/scanner-error-with-nextint)

[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo/13102066#13102066)

[How to use java.util.Scanner to correctly read user input from System.in and act on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446599/how-to-use-java-util-scanner-to-correctly-read-user-input-from-system-in-and-act)

[The Scanner Class](https://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Ebvanderz/cs365/examples/datacheck.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20have%20finished%20using%20a%20Scanner%2C%20such,will%20have%20a%20memory%20leak%20in%20your%20program%3A)
[String formatting in Java Scanner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471193/string-formatting-in-java-scanner-class/42471816#42471816)

[Java Scanner doesn't wait for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450524/java-scanner-doesnt-wait-for-user-input)

[Java String Scanner input does not wait for info, moves directly to next statement. How to wait for info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877529/java-string-scanner-input-does-not-wait-for-info-moves-directly-to-next-stateme?rq=1)

[String formatting in Java Scanner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471193/string-formatting-in-java-scanner-class/42471816#42471816)

[Scanner.html#nextInt() javase 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

[Scanner.html#nextInt() Javase 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())

Those answers do not work for me. I still get an infinite loop. Any advice? Thank you.

**EDIT**

First I enter an invalid selection, say 8, `nextInt()` will wait for input. The program will allow to enter an integer again. But in the second round, `nextInt()` does not wait for input.

If I tried this:

```
       try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            selection = scanner.nextInt();  // reads only one int. does not finish the line.
            scanner.nextLine(); // consume '\n' to finish the line
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
```

The `scanner.nextLine()` will not being executed after the first round. It back to `try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in))` to close the `Scanner`. Then I got `NoSuchElementException`.

**EDIT**

The main problem is `nextInt()` is not waiting for input in the second round. There should be a way to block the program waiting for input, before the scanner being closed. [javase 7 oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) saying:

> public boolean hasNext()

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

**EDIT**

*ENV*: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2, jdk 14.0.2

Comment: Have you tried throwing away the next input by using `scanner.next()`?

Comment: The `Scanner` is being closed automatically since in a  try-with-resource, that is also closing `System.in` so on second call, `hasNext` will always return false since the standard input it closed (bad practice IMHO) - remove the try-with-resource and open the `Scanner` only once in `main`

Comment: It seems weird to try using a new Scanner for every line. I found a couple tutorials in line with my expectation of how java input works, but Scanners just don't seem to wait for input today.

Comment: It may depend on where you're running it. Of the example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249324/how-to-get-java-to-wait-for-user-input : A LeetCode playground fails while IntelliJ IDEA behaves as expected.

Comment: In this type of program we often include a counter so as to request the input a few times, 5 for example, and then close the program (or ask the user if they want to quit). We can event append "try 2 / 5" etc to the request for information.

Comment: `public static Integer inputSelection () {
        Integer selection = 0;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                selection = scanner.nextInt(); 
                scanner.nextLine(); 
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return selection;
    }`

This works. `try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)` and `scanner.close()` seems close the scanner instead of waiting input, when `nextInt()` or `nextLine()` failed . But I dont know, why.

Answer (score 0):

try to set keepRunning on false, if it so happens, that you reach in to a case state.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the `break` statement breaks out of the current iteration to the next enclosing level of control. It seems you expect the `break` in the `switch` to break you out of the `while` loop, but it only gets you out of the current case.

Try changing the `keepRunning` flag within any of the cases representing a success condition, rather than the failure condition. `keepRunning` should be changed to false when you get good input, not bad input. You only want to continue asking when you get bad input, correct?

Comment: `Exit` is the only way to stop the loop. Bad input should block the loop waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe don't quite understand what you mean.But I think writing it this way works fine.I just tried it again, so that I don't get stuck in an infinite loop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean keepRunning = true;
        while (keepRunning) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Start --- ");
                Integer selection = inputSelection();
                //Integer selection = Integer.parseInt(selectionString);
                String email;
                switch (selection) {
                    case 1:
                        // inputDate();
                        System.out.println("Do 1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //inputEmail();
                        System.out.println("Do 2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //inputName();
                        System.out.println("Do 3");

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        // Exit
                        keepRunning = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 3: ");
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Integer inputSelection() {
        Integer selection = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                selection = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return selection;
    }
```

Comment: if you type `1` or `3` it infinitely prints `Start --- Please enter a number between 1 and 3`

Comment: I ditched the "inputSelection" method here.

Comment: I didn't get stuck in an infinite loop after entering "1" and "3"

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the original problem.

Comment: The original question Entering any number will get into an infinite loop.Of course, except for "5".

Comment: I just want to put all input logic into a method, say, inputSelect(), inputEmail(), inputDate(). @ShawnGao So that they can be wrapped in a class, say util class.

Comment: Maybe, **"try(){}"** will cause the resource in parentheses to be automatically closed when leaving the **"try"** section.

Comment: Now, I can sure that `try()` can close scanner automatically following the [DOC](https://web.eecs.utk.edu/~bvanderz/cs365/examples/datacheck.html#:~:text=When%20you%20have%20finished%20using%20a%20Scanner%2C%20such,will%20have%20a%20memory%20leak%20in%20your%20program%3A). The problem is there should be a way to waiting input, before the scanner being closed.

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.hasNext()` is returning false, which causes it to return 0, which is out of bounds. This is because the `Scanner` object is being closed, therefore closing `System.in`. Check the comment for credit.

If you replace the if statement in `inputSelection` with the following, it prints `e` and infinite loops.

```java
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
    selection = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
} else {
    System.out.println("e");
    while (true) {}
}
```

Comment: "I do not know why" -> because the `Scanner` is being closed, closing `System.in`

Comment: [Scanner.html#hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) should wait for input, right? So that `nextInt()` could get the int.

Comment: So There should be a way that the scanner waiting for input before it is being closed.

Comment: `if(!scanner.hasNext())` gives infinite loop either. The problem still exists. `hasNext()` not block for waiting input. But [Oracle docs javase 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) says : `This method may block while waiting for input to scan.`

Comment: [Oracle Doc javase 14 hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()). `This method may block while waiting for input to scan.`